# Problem using c.Sendfile(path) in fiber (golang web framework)

Tags: api, go, video-streaming, fibers, go-fiber

I have saved some of videos in specific paths. I want the video to be displayed when the API is called. I do this using `c.SendFile()`. The problem is that by calling the API once by **vlc** or **browser**, it is called several times. I realized this from `fmt.Println("called")`.

What is the problem?

```
func main() {

    app := fiber.New()

    app.Get("/video", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        fmt.Println("called")
        return c.SendFile("./videos/2022/12/17/1a191775-a3ab-427a-932e-ebbb3d2879b1/video-360.mp4");
      
      })

    app.Listen(":3030")
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how you are calling the api?

Comment: @TrevorJohnson I put 127.0.0.1:3030/video URL in VLC in the path Media/Open network Stream, I also call the API in the browser (google chrome). The video is played, there is no problem, but the API is called several times